# Modify select identifiers in Sql Query using calcite

Tags: sql, apache-calcite

I want to modify a SQL query using Calcite. For example

`SELECT values FROM data` to

`SELECT values as v FROM data`

I could access SqlNode of select identifier using SqlVisiter implementation.

```
public Object visit(SqlCall sqlCall) {
    SqlNodeList selectList = ((SqlSelect) sqlCall).getSelectList();
    for (SqlNode sqlNode : selectList) {
        System.out.println(sqlNode.toString());
    }
```

Now what should I do to update SqlNode?

Answer (score 1):

The `SqlNode` objects in the select list will be instances of `SqlIdentifier` in this case. So you'll have to cast `sqlNode` to a `SqlIdentifier` and then you can call `.setName(0, "NEW_NAME")`. After this, you call `unparse` on the original root node to get the new query back.